# storing textarea content in ebean database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I think the question might be a bit stupid - I am working on my first Play project and thus I am still in train to try to gain an overview over the software ;)

Well, I have a page containing a textarea. A user should be able to enter text there and store it permanently in the standard ebean database.
But storing never works and I can't find out the reason!

This is the class definition for the database object:

```
public class Entry extends Model {
    @Required
    public String   text;   
    public String   studentName;
    @Id
    public long     id;
    public static   Finder<Long, Entry> finder = new Finder<Long, Entry>( Long.class, Entry.class);

    public static Entry getMe(Long id) {
        return finder.byId(id);
    }
    public static void saveMe(Entry toDataBase) {
        toDataBase.save();
    }
    // ....
 }
```

Here is the text area:

```
@(entryForm: Form[Entry])
@import helper._
@main("xy") {

<h1>report for @entryForm("studentName")</h1>

    @form(routes.Application.storeReport()) {
        @textarea(entryForm("report:"))
        <input type="submit" value="Store Report">
    }
}
```

In the `Application.storeReport()` method entryForm.bindFromRequest().hasErrors() is always true..

and changing `@textarea(entryForm("report:"))` to `@textarea(entryForm("text"))` (..to tell the thing, which of the 3 Entry fields I actually want to fill) even causes a PersistenceException:

> "the type [class models.Entry] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().]"

Orienting on the [ToDoList example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaTodoList) I can't detect how I could register an entitly else than letting it extend the play.db.ebean.Model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot the @Entity annotation on your Entry class.